# MongoDB Aggregate Match with String char

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My sample document is

```
[
  {
    "id": 1234,
    "close": "11100",
    "products": [
      {
        "productId": 111
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1235,
    "close": "10101",
    "products": [
      {
        "productId": 111
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I wanted to fetch the documents only if the 'close' field **second char** is 0

> note: index of char is dynamic

expected output:

```
{
        "id": 1235,
        "close": "10101",
        "products": [
          {
            "productId": 111
          }
        ]
      }
```

is there any way to filter the documents in the match stage?

Here is a sample doc [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1og3REbmWFX)

I tried this aggregation in the $project stage, but I wanted to filter this in $match stage. Thanks

```
close: {
    $not: {
      $regex: {
        $substr: ["$close", 2, 1],

        regex: "[1]",
      },
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work with `$regex` operator

`^` - Starts with

`.` - Any character

This will match the document with the `close` field containing '0' in the second character.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      close: {
        $regex: "^.0"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dg2CC0vgmZB)

So if you are looking for a dynamic index position:

```
^.{index position -1}0
```

For example, if you are looking for a second character, your regex pattern will be: `^.{1}0`.

Comment: The question specified: `note: index of char is dynamic`

Comment: Hi @Yong Shun, Thanks for your help. If I want to match with the substring, how we can do it? Ex: "close": "10101". if the 2nd char to 4th char contains 1 I want to return the doc.  I tried this expression  (?<=^.{1}).{3}1.* but not worked

Comment: Hi, is it another regex pattern without checking the 2nd character is 0 as your original question? If yes, you should work with: `^(?:.{1}1|.{2}1|.{3}1)`  [Demo @ Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/bE3hpV/1)

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [{$substr: ["$close", inxOfWantedChar, 1]}, "0"]}}}
])
```

See How it works on the [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yOkseL1PZOk)